# EJS Form GET Request with a search bar not working as expected

Tags: html, node.js, forms, ejs, routeparams

I am trying make a static search bar that currently is redirected to '/'. That is just the current situation. But the main problem is that whatever the input is, the output is always '*h*'

I am using **nodejs** and **ejs**

.

***request.ejs***

```
      <form action="/request/search" method="GET">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="search"
              id="search"
              placeholder="Search for Books"
              class="search"
            />
            <button class="search-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div class="imae"></div>
      </form>
```

---

***server.js***

---

```
app.get('/request/search?:search', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

***output***

```
{ search: 'h' }
```

Am I Doing something wrong, Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify, but it appears you're using express.

Use the `req.query` object rather than `req.params`, as params are used for URLs with routes, not query parameters. With that being said, you do not need the `:search` in your request URL match. I can't explain why it's receiving a value of 'h', but this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use POST instead of GET in the form Method

```
<HTML>
    <form action="/request/search" method="POST">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="search"
          id="search"
          placeholder="Search for Books"
          class="search"
        />
        <button class="search-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

IN js side.
`app.get('/request/search', (req, res) => { console.log(req.body); res.redirect('/'); });`